# Is it possible to set a session var from apache?

Tags: php, apache

is it possible to set a session var from apache?

i mean i have

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/
</VirtualHost>
```

pointing to the main site and then i would like for the users who open a sub domain like 
en.domain.com, to load the language file EN and so on..

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName en.domain.com
ServerAlias en.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/ [????]
</VirtualHost>
```

how can I pass any var from this config file?
or how can i set it? other solutions? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mod_env to set environment variables in your config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName en.domain.com
  ServerAlias en.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/
  SetEnv LANG en
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you can pick them up from PHP:

```
$lang = getenv('LANG');
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [SetEnv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) in apache and [getenv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) in php. That will pass a variable from Apache into PHP, but setting it in the $_SESSION is pointless since the value from apache is kinda static.

```
// in apache
SetEnv VARNAME myvalue

// in php
echo getenv('VARNAME');
```

Answer (score 1):

$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] would show this but $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"] might be a better candidate for your problem at hand.

Comment: using `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` can be troublesome.  Just because a user has a browser that normally displays content in one language does not mean they **always** want the content in that language.  If they have deliberately selected a URL of `en.domain.com` then the server should respect that choice rather than taking the default.

Comment: I agree completely, however it is not entirely clear that this is the use-case from the question. Just pinging in on the Other solutions-part of OPs question.

Answer (score 1):

You can set an [environment variable](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html) which can then be accessed by PHP.  The vhost config would look something like this:

```
SetEnv UNIQUE_ENV_VAR_NAME yourValue
```

then in PHP

```
if (isset($_SERVER['UNIQUE_ENV_VAR_NAME'])) {
    executeYourCode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already answered, mod_env is an answer. Another possibility is using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and you might be able to combine many of your virtual hosts.... for example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^([^.]*)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$(subdomain)? - [E=SUBDOMAIN:%1]
```